# Visa to UK from France to non citizen

Tags: visas, uk, france, jordanian-citizens

Im Jordanian, and married to a french citizen! I currently live and work in Paris, I applied for a UK visa on the 23rd of april and up until now I got no answer ! does it take longer for non citizens to get their visa?

Comment: For non-citizens of which country?

Comment: non citizens from jordan

Comment: @Gloria D What type of visa?

Comment: I applied for a tourist visa

Comment: Are you traveling with your spouse?

Comment: he might join me later, but i didnt mention that in the application

Answer (score 3):

> Does it take longer for non citizens to get their visa?

*Everybody* applying for a UK visa in France is a non-citizen, because French citizens do not need, and cannot get, UK visas (as long as the UK remains in the European Union).

This is because of the EU [right of free movement](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=legissum:l33152) enjoyed by union citizens and, under certain circumstances, their non-EU family members.  Because of that right, you are entitled to a *free* visa that should be issued *quickly* if you are traveling to the UK with (or to join) your spouse.

If you are traveling without your spouse, you'll just have to wait for a result from your current application.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question,  i think i just have to wait ! wish me luck